# NodeJS server only works on hosting machine, not on other devices

Tags: node.js, localhost

I have set up a Node.js server on my computer, using the following code:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, "0.0.0.0");
console.log('Server running');
```

Now, when I use this computer to go to `http://localhost:1337/`, `http://127.0.0.1:1337/` or `http://192.168.178.28:1337/` (`192.168.178.28` being my IPv4 address), it works fine.
When i try and use my iPad to visit the last one (ipv4 address) it doesn't work. Why could this be?

Comment: Are you on Windows? Try disabling your Windows Firewall.

Comment: I am indeed on Windows, and I already had Firewall disabled

Comment: What is your iPad browser and what is the error message?

Comment: I've tried Safari and Chrome. There is no error message, it just can't connect

Comment: How did you check your ip? `ipconfig` - right?. Have you tried different port number? Logout from Win and log back in? Restart node?

Comment: ipconfig indeed. I have tried changing port number and restarting node several times. I will now try restarting my computer.

Comment: Unfortunately, restarting didn't help.

Comment: have you tried accessing the site from your phone?

Comment: Yes, I have done that

Comment: are you sure that your iPad is on the same network?

Comment: Yes, I am sure both are on the same network

Answer (score 1):

Okay, turns out resetting my router did the job. Thanks to lazlojuly and Gonzalo Bahamondez for trying to help!